# Phone number reg expression and concatenation in sql insert into statement

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
$db->Query("INSERT INTO `userdata`(email,phone) values('".$form_email."','".$form_phone."')");
```

Data gets entered properly. However, I need to concatenate `+91` country code before the phone is entered in the database. I tried with `+` and `&` operators... Not sure how to write it in quotes or if there is any other syntax.
Note: phone number type in database is `varchar(15)`. do I need to change this?

**Question 2**

I am using this expression `/^[789]\d{9}$/` to validate phone number. Should start with `7` `8` or `9` and the length should be 10 digits. When I enter `7777777777` or `8888888888` or `9999999999`, it just accepts.. Is there any other way of validating to ensure user enters valid number?

One way I can think of is total up all 10 numbers and restrict if the total is `>=70` but is this the correct logic? not sure how to write it in expression form.

Comment: With regard to Question #2, what constitutes a "valid" phone number here?  Unless your country's phone number has some kind of checksum digit or valid range of numbers, your options are limited.  One approach could be to check the "entropy" of your string (an [example in C#](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/868/calculating-entropy-of-a-string) is available); the gist is that you count up the unique digits in your string, which in your examples would be very low.

Comment: Thanks not sure if counting up unique digits is better way. As far as constitution is concerned, its a 10 digit number that starts with 7, 8 or 9 as scripted in the expression now even 7777777777 is also valid as per expression and it is 10 digit too but is not a valid phone number. Now if we total this up, the answer is 70. This is the only logic I can think of. If the total is >=70, it should restrict the user with an alert of invalid number. The problem is how to write this as a regex string...

Comment: You might modify your validation so that you can refer back to your first digit and ensure that it's not continuously repeated for the following 9 digits.  The following regex does that: first digit is 7-9, forward assertion that the next 9 digits aren't identical to the first, and then a match against the next 9 digits to ensure it's numeric:  `/^([789])(?!\1{9})\d{9}$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can merge

```
$form_phone= "+91" .$form_phone;
```

Your experssion working fine only

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x85d6qbn/1/)

Comment: It is phone and not email :) Looks like a type. By the way I have a line $phn = $db->EscapeString($_POST['form_phone']); can this be merged here in php?

Comment: Yes , You can concatenate here

Comment: appreciate if you can provide the syntax. Thanks

Comment: $phn = "+91" . $db->EscapeString($_POST['form_phone']);

Comment: @user3736026 Updated in answer

Comment: Saw your demo. thanks. $phn = "+91" . $db->EscapeString($_POST['form_phone']); has worked. Now if I want to concatenate "+91" and last 10 digits of form_phone then how would the syntax look like? I tried $phn = "+91" . $db->EscapeString($_POST[substr('form_phone',-10]); but it did not work.

Comment: Why are you trying that?. Anyway you ll get 10 digit number from UI.

Comment: sorry for the incomplete question. I modified the expression to /^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$/; This takes care of users who would already put +91 or 91 or 091 and more combinations before the number so the form_phone value will be more than 10 digits that is why i wanted to extract last 10 digits and prefix with +91 to keep all the records intact the same way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60899/discussion-between-user3736026-and-ashokhein).

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate +91 before the phone number is entered in the database:

```
$db->Query("INSERT INTO `userdata`(email,phone) values('"+91".".$form_email."','".$form_phone."')");
```

I don't understand your question about the regex.  If you want a phone number to be 10 digits beginning with a 7,8 or 9 then the expression is correct.

Comment: I am going to try this... thank you. Any idea about the expression?

Comment: The expression is correct as far as I can see.  What else would you like to do with it?  The extra validation you suggest of calculating the total would be redundant.

Comment: I agree. However, 9999999999 is also valid as per expression but is not a valid phone number. If we total this up, the answer is 90 so that we can restrict this as an invalid number. But i do not know how to enter this restriction/validation in the regex string

Comment: To specifically restrict 9999999999, use this expression: ^(?!9999999999)[789]\d{9}$

Comment: I thought about it but it does not resolve the issue as 7777777777, 8888888888, 7979797979, 8787878787 all fits the expression but not a valid number :( summing up atleast gives some logic but i do not know how to write it in the regex syntax

Comment: Well I don't know the rules for phone numbers in your country but to exclude a specific number use (?!number) as per my example above.  That's all I can suggest as I don't know where you are or what the rules are.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$form_email = "+91{$form_email}"; 
$db->Query("INSERT INTO `userdata`(email,phone) values ('{$form_email}','{$form_phone}')");
```

Don't understand the regex question I'm afraid...